# How to define parameter datatype in order to restrict other data inputs in Python

Tags: python, class, constructor

I was wondering, is there a way to define a datatype for a parameter for a function, in my case the def **init** constructor so that when I create an object, I can only pass arguments that correlate with the set datatype.

For example:

```
class Checking(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, acc_number, acc_holder, acc_balance):
        self.acc_num = acc_number
        self.acc_holder = acc_holder
        self.acc_balance = acc_balance

random = Checking("A84829", "Roger ", "a637.23")
```

So, when I create the object random and pass the arguments, I want the program to not work since I entered in the incorrect datatypes. Right now, the program works and I can't figure out why since I am very new to python.

I tried doing this as well:

```
class Checking(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, acc_number: int, acc_holder: str, acc_balance: float):
```

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language, you need to write the code for this yourself. Or use a library, like `pydantic`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry I am a bit confused about what you mean when you say write the code for this yourself?

Comment: Just as juanpa.arrivillaga mentions, Python is quacking like a duck and "“If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, it’s a duck” regarding to types (read: dynamic typing...)

You can check realpython-doc here for more information:
https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/

A builtin function to check if a variable is of a specific type is `isinstance`:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance

Comment: @Aman I mean *you have to write the code that checks the types yourself*. Again, there are libraries for handling this, e.g. `pydantic`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you sir!

Answer (score 1):

In python, type hinting (which is what you did in the second example) is not enforced and is only used by your IDE to provide proper code completion if it supports that. Secondly, as stated in the comment above python is dynamically typed, meaning that a variable can have any type at any point in the program.

One solution is to explicitly check the types of your input as such:

```py
class Checking(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, acc_number, acc_holder, acc_balance):
        if not isinstance(acc_number, int): 
            throw Error('account number must be an integer')
        if not isinstance(acc_holder, str): 
            throw Error('account holder must be an string')
        if not isinstance(acc_balance, float): 
            throw Error('account balance must be an float')
        self.acc_num = acc_number
        self.acc_holder = acc_holder
        self.acc_balance = acc_balance
```

This will cause Python to throw an error whenever a parameter is the wrong type.

Comment: I think I understand this. Could you just explain what the "isinstance" is in this case. I think what you are saying is that is the instance and specifically, the instance plus the account number for example, an int, if not, throw error.

Comment: Yes exactly, isinstance takes in 2 arguments, returning true if the first argument is the same type as the second argument and false if it is not. isinstance is a built-in function in python. In words each of these statements is saying "if the parameter is not the type I want, throw the error, otherwise let the program continue"

Comment: Thanks! I just got confused by the weird wording "if not isinstance"

Comment: @Aman `ifinstance(i,int)` can be spoken as *if `i` is an instance of `int`*.

Answer (score 1):

As @juanpa.arrivillaga mentions, a good way to do this is with a library like `pydantic`.

Here is an example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Checking(BaseModel):
    acc_num: int
    acc_holder: str
    acc_balance: float


Checking.acc_number = 1234
Checking.acc_holder = "Roger"
```